# Jump to Poll Results

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to show poll results on the same page without a page refresh.

The problem is that the **poll itself** takes about **three times the page space** as compared to the **results**. When users vote, depending on how far they have scrolled down the page, they are not able to view results unless they scroll up.

I was thinking that I would be able to do something like `<form action="#results">` to jump to the results but it does not work. My guess is the reason is because AJAX uses the PHP script from a different page than the page the poll is on.

Is there a way to jump to the results?

For those that want to know the URL of the page, it is http://kokorugs.com with the poll on the right column of the page:

[image]

Comment: Are you using jQuery? There are 'scrollTo' functions out there, I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, I can use a jQuery solution. I was assuming there would be an easier way but jQuery is always an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice page. Just had a look, you can do this just fine from the browser console. I'd assume the same to be true from the code on the page itself.

First, get the position of the  element:

```
var topOfPollBox_y = document.getElementById('poll').offsetTop
```

Followed by scrolling the document to this position:

```
window.scrollTo(0, topOfPollBox_y);
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you! I will one day have to spend some time to learn what AJAX can do.

Comment: It was rather, wasn't it? - but hey, like I say: building a nuclear bomb isn't all that hard - it's the working-out how that's the (most) difficult part! Getting the info from someone else does ease the burden somewhat.. Ajax can be awesome - handling the back button is in my mind the nastiest part - you'll have little-to-no trouble with ajax, I expect. :)